# How to mock final field? mockito/powermock

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have same class

```
class MyCalss{
     final static SomeClass field  = new SomeClass();
     ...
}
```

I should to mock instance of MyCalss. This mock should contain field like real object.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a framework that allows for mocking calls to constructors such as JMockit or Powermock.

[Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects)

[JMockit](http://abhinandanmk.blogspot.in/2012/06/jmockit-tutoriallearn-it-today-with.html#constructor)

Answer (score 5):

Mocking operates on *methods* and *interfaces*, not *fields*; furthermore, it operates on *instance members*, not *static members*. Mockito and Powermock are not the right tools to solve this problem.

Though you can [use reflection to set final fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3301635/1426891), you're effectively working around your own declaration, and are subject to the limitations and hazards of [JLS 17.5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3).

A better design would be to rewrite the method in the system under test to inject its SomeClass dependency:

```java
public void methodUnderTest() {
  methodUnderTest(MyClass.field);
}

/** Package-visible for testing. Test this method instead. */
void methodUnderTest(SomeClass someClass) {
  someClass.firePhotonTorpedoes();
}
```